# Power bi matrix table row values for measures

Tags: powerbi, dax

I created a matrix to which I added:

Rows:

Columns:

- Date (From date lookup table)

Values:

- Measure 1
- Measure 2
- Measure 3

So I get the following matrix.

|  | Sep-23 | Oct-23 | Nov-23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Measure 1 | 95% | 96% | 98% |
| Measure 2 | 98% | 97% | 95% |
| Measure 3 | 97% | 99% | 100% |

I would like to add a row to categorize my measures. So I would get something like this:

|  | Sep-23 | Oct-23 | Nov-23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **- Cat 1** |  |  |  |
| Measure 1 | 95% | 96% | 98% |
| Measure 2 | 98% | 97% | 95% |
| **- Cat 1** |  |  |  |
| Measure 3 | 97% | 99% | 100% |

I though about it but have no clue on how to approach this.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new table similar to:

| Category | Label |
| --- | --- |
| Cat 1 | Measure 1 (or any string) |
| Cat 1 | Measure 2 |
| Cat 2 | Measure 3 |

Then create a new measure with:

```
Category measure = 
  var v = SWITCH( SELECTEDVALUE('Category'[Label]) ,
    "Measure 1 (or any string)", [Measure 1],
    "Measure 2", [Measure 2],
    "Measure 3", [Measure 3]
  )
  RETURN IF(ISINSCOPE('Category'[Label]), v)
```

Then for your Matrix, add `'Category'[Category]` and `'Category'[Label]` to the `Rows`, your `Date` to `Columns`, and `[Category measure]` to `Values`.